# How to Tidy messy dates in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I have this data frame called My_dataframe

```
Date <-c("2020-02-24", "2020-03-24", "2020-04-24", "2020-05-24", "2020-02-24", "2020-03-24", 
"2020-04-24", "2020-05-24", "2020-02-24", "2020-03-24", "2020-04-24", "2020-05-24")

Country <- c("Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "India", "India", "India", "India", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil")

Region <- c("Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "South America", "South America", "South America", "South America")

Cases <- c(3, 4, 7, 8, 21, 22, 26, 33, 15, 13, 44, 10)
My_dataframe <- data.frame(Date, Country, Region, Cases)
```

If you pay attention, the days keep repeating in the same column "Date": you have all the days for a country and then all the days for the next country.
So, I want to sum the cases, by date,  in each region, and have the regions disposed like variables (columns). What I want to achieve is something like:

```
# each day appears once instead of repeating

Date <- c("2020-02-24", "2020-03-24", "2020-04-24", "2020-05-24")
Europe <- c(25, 36, 45, 40)
Asia <- c(12, 7, 15, 21)
America <- c(33, 31, 27, 29)

New_dataframe <- data.frame(Date, Europe, Asia, America)
```

Sorry if the question is dumb, i'm beggining in this world. I appreciate if someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider` and specify the `values_fn` as `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
My_dataframe %>% 
   select(-Country) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = Region, values_from  = Cases, values_fn = sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can group your table by `Date` and `Region` to calculate the totals, then use `pivot_wider` to make a column for each region:

```
library(tidyverse)

My_dataframe %>% 
     group_by(Date, Region) %>% 
     summarise(total = sum(Cases)) %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = Region, values_from = total)
```

Depending on what you're doing with the data, it might be better not to do the pivot_wider step until later. Your original dataframe is in a "tidy data" format which is easier to work with if you want to create plots or do further analysis.

Comment: Man, you awesome. Thank you very much